# Sharepoint 2013 Rest API _api/Web/SiteUserInfoList filter Name

Tags: 2013, jquery, rest

I have some trouble to use the Sharepoint2013 Rest API _api/Web/SiteUserInfoList. 
I need to use a $filter on the Name. I get always a 400 Bad Request. 
This is my endopoint rest ....my_site.../_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items/?$filter=Name eq 'i:0#.w|bs\user' 
How can I filter on the Name?

Thanks, Nk

Comment: have you try with %27 instead of ' ?

Comment: I think you need to encode the user name since it contains tons of chars not allowed in a querystring :) You could for example use encodeURIComponent: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: encodeURIComponent() solved my problem :) 
I tried to use encodeURI() but it didn't work.
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Name` property value (claim format) should be encoded, for example using `encodeURIComponent` function or as an alternative you could specify `UserName` property instead:

```
/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$filter=UserName eq 'username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `#` in the username to `%23`.

```
http://spsite/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items/?$filter=Name eq 'i:0%23.w|bs\user'
```